# What are the rules of this "Frog rescue game" from Boots?

Tags: identify-this-game

I picked up this game second hand but found it doesn't include any instructions.

It has a cross-shaped board that you assemble jigsaw style with a tower in the middle. The back of the box says "in the exciting race to the castle, all the dice are rolled together on each turn and all the players move at the same time". Dice are coloured, one matching each player. But there also appear to be some elaborations on the basic structure of rolling dice and advancing eg there are some special squares - dragons and thorny bushes - and each player has three different characters - a knight, a wizard and a princess.

We'd love to know how all this is implemented. Of course we can make up our own house rules but would like to know the official ones too.

There's a date on the inside of the box of 2004 which could be when it was manufactured.

[1]: [image][image]

Comment: Who is the manufacturer? Do you have a pic of the front of the box? Is there a copyright date shown on the box or the board pieces?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Picture added of the other side. No date that I can see. Manufacturer is Boots, a large UK pharmacy.

Comment: The box has a 'Boots' logo.  For those outside United Kingdom that's a high street store that sells mainly health care products.  The branch where I live a a baby/children's section where such a game could be found.  If this game is in print or not I've no idea as I can't find this game listed anywhere.  It might be worth contacting Boots directly to see if they can help you.

Comment: Actually, just spotted a date on an inside flap of 2004.

Comment: Have you searched online using the barcode?

Comment: @bensvenssohn thanks for the suggestion! No luck though, unless there are any special tricks. I just googled barcode 5045094703395

Comment: I suspect that if you were able to get the website archived at http://web.archive.org/web/20050307215227/http://www.bootslearningstore.com/stuck.htm to load (It requires Flash 5), you might find the rules or at least more hints at them, but that's where I got stuck.